# Google Compute Engine VPN DNS

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have established a VPN connection between my location A (GCE VM) and location B (non-GCE).
I would like my location B systems to reference location A (GCE) systems by name instead of IP.

What options are there for bridging these two environments?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simpler way is to add an entry in hosts file available both on Linux (/etc/hosts) and Windows (C - > Windows - > System32 - > drivers - > etc - > hosts) and bind IP to a name.

Alternatively in more complex environments you could setup a DNS server, and use separate views to separate internal and external DNS information as an example see [1].

Ciao
Paolo

Link:
[1] - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bind9-named-configure-views/

Comment: Thank you Paolo.  On the GCE side for the very few instances that need to communicate over the VPN back to the location B side I am using /etc/hosts entries.  On the location B/corporate side I have created DNS entries for referencing the GCE instances.  I was hoping someone had experience integrating GCE with their main network and would share.